# Sql Server ODBC connection error Table access error

Tags: sql-server, odbc

```
TSystem.Data.Odbc.OdbcException was unhandled
Message: ERROR [42S00] [SmartWare Software][SmartWare ODBC Driver][ISAM]Table access error
```

Just curious as to what usually causes this error, or how better to find out what is causing my error. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on Tracing via the tracing tab of the ODBC Data Source Administrator, and you'll get a log of every action and be potentially able to see at what point the error is generated.

Comment: Wish I could, it is in an ssis package.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference, assuming the package is using a DSN on the server.